# Unable to update database information with ajax and php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to use ajax to serialize my form and then update the database. I checked the SQL query in my database and it is working fine. I believe the problem is with the serialization of the form. I  noticed a typo and thought that would fix it but it did not. What did I do wrong?

See fiddle for HTML & jQuery code: http://jsfiddle.net/1t3gaz2k/

PHP Code

```
$parcel_id = isset($_POST['parcel_id']) ? $_POST['parcel_id'] : null;
//$appeal_address_match = isset($_POST['AppealAddressMatch']) ? 1 : 0; (add to sql statement -- appeal_address_match='". $appeal_address_match ."',)
$date_appeal_received = isset($_POST['DateAppealReceived']) ? $_POST['DateAppealReceived'] : null;
$bos_meeting_date = isset($_POST['BosMeetingDate']) ? $_POST['BosMeetingDate'] : null;
$late_returns_date = isset($_POST['LateReturnsDate']) ? $_POST['LateReturnsDate'] : null;
$determination_notice = isset($_POST['DeterminationNoticeSet']) ? $_POST['DeterminationNoticeSet'] : null;
$final_determination = isset($_POST['FinalDetermination']) ? $_POST['FinalDetermination'] : null;
$analysis_recommendation = isset($_POST['AnalysisRecommendation']) ? $_POST['AnalysisRecommendation'] : null;
$email_address = isset($_POST['EmailAddress']) ? $_POST['EmailAddress'] : null;
$phone_number = isset($_POST['PhoneNumber']) ? $_POST['PhoneNumber'] : null;

if(isset($_GET['parcel_id'])) {
    $db = new ezSQL_mysql(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);
    $result = $db->query("UPDATE parcels SET date_appeal_received='" . $date_appeal_received . "', 

                        bos_meeting_date='". $date_appeal_received ."', 
                        late_returns_date='". $late_returns_date ."', 
                        determination_notice_sent_date='". $determination_notice ."', 
                        final_determination='". $final_determination ."', 
                        analysis_recommendation='". $analysis_recommendation ."', 
                        email_address='". $email_address ."', 
                        phone_number='". $phone_number ."'
                        WHERE parcel_id='" . $parcel_id ."'");
    /*if ($result == TRUE) {
        echo '{"success":true}';
    } else {
        echo '{"success":false}';
    }    */

    if($result) echo 'true';
    else echo 'false';

}

?>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I'm not getting any error. It's just not updating the database.

Comment: Where is your Ajax Script?
Are you really using Ajax request?
Try access dev tools in you browser to search any possible response error.

Comment: You say you think the problem is in the serialisation of your form, but you haven't posted that code. See [ask]

Comment: Are you sure you are running the PHP file? I'd suggest confirming that and doing a var_dump to make sure you are passing the arguments correctly.

Comment: I put my HTML and jQuery in the fiddle link. I edited the post to make it more clear. Can someone tell me why there is a -4? Am I not allowed to ask a question that someone might find stupid?

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing a `GET`: `if(isset($_GET['parcel_id'])) {`

When it looks like you should be checking a `POST`: `if(isset($_POST['parcel_id'])) {`

No error because it's not making it past your `if` statement.

Comment: It appears that this is the correct answer... but should note that this query is vulnerable to SQL injection. Take appropriate steps for sanitizing your variables before executing the update.